# Agrupar datos solo con 4 digitos

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Mi problema se resume de esta manera, tenga una `tabla`
en este formato de eventos importantes.

```
| fechas       |
| ------------ |
| 2022-3-7    |
| 2022-6-1    |
| 2021-1-5    |
| 2020-2-9    |
| 2019-5-9    |
| 2019-7-4    |
```

Lo que se quiere hacer es un conteo de esas fechas y agruparlas y que solo se incluyan los primeros 4 digitos que son los años y que quede de la siguiente manera

```
| Fechas       | Conteo        |
| ------------ | ------------- |
| 2022         | 2             |
| 2021         | 1             |
| 2020         | 1             |
| 2019         | 2             |
```

Comment: ¿tu que has probado al respecto?  Recuerda que puedes modificar tu pregunta agregando lo que hayas intentado pulsando el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta

Comment: Inténtalo con `YEAR(fecha)`

Comment: Y si no es un campo tipo fecha, usa `LEFT(Fechas,4)`

Comment: Lo solucionaste?